# Node-rsa SHA1 message signature length

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa, sha1

I'm trying to get an sha-1 signature of a message with a private key.

```
var client_private = new NodeRSA(require('fs').readFileSync('../providers/sirena/keys/client_private.txt'), {signingAlgorithm: 'sha1'});
var message_signature = client_private.sign(message);
```

And “message_signature” appears to have 256 bytes.

In the other hand  simple bash command

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary -out message.signature -sign providers/sirena/keys/client_private.txt message
```

returns 128 which is required by my provider.

Am I doing something wrong? What should I do to get 128-bytes signature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was simple as I thought.

In fact I had 2 KiB long private key instead of 1 KiB.